# Printing result of a query with regexp_like

Tags: sql, presto

I have records that starts with the word `point` and records that does not start with the word `point`.

I am trying to count how many of each and I have this query:

```
select count(*) from tbl
where regexp_like(name, '.*point.*')
```

The query above is working.  I want to know how  can I print the result like this:

```
names_with_point    names_without_point
  234                     120
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`count_if`](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/functions/aggregate.html#count_if):

```sql
select count_if(regexp_like(name, '.*point.*')) as names_with_point
    , count_if(not regexp_like(name, '.*point.*')) as names_without_point
from dataset
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure count_if is an ANSI SQL function.

```js
select count(case when regexp_like(name, '.*point.*') THEN name end) as  names_with_point,
       count(case when not regexp_like(name, '.*point.*') THEN name end ) as names_without_point
          from dataset
```

Comment: OP has tagged the question with presto which supports `count_if` according to the docs.

Comment: yes, you are right.